# Are Unix and Linux API headers compatible with C++?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I have previously written C++ code that `#include`s Unix and Linux API headers and these programs have produced the expected behavior. That said, I don't know if this can be relied on. It's possible that incompatibilities between C and C++ could cause valid C headers to act in unexpected ways when used by C++ programs.

Can Unix and Linux API headers reliably be used by code that will be compiled as C++?

Is this a goal of the authors of those headers? Or are those headers only intended to be valid C?

Are there any known pitfalls when doing this?

Obviously the Unix and Linux distributions are numerous and I don't expect an answer to address every distribution one by one. My expectation is that the same answer will apply to almost all distributions of Unix and Linux and exceptions will prove the rule. If this assumption is wrong, an explanation of that would also be a valid answer.

By Unix headers I mean these:

http://www.unix.org/version3/apis/headers.html

By Linux headers I mean the headers provided by Linux distributions usually as a package named "linux-headers" that allow programs to interact with the Linux kernel. For example, this Debian package:

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/kernel/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64

I realize the Unix link is only a specification and that each Linux distribution is different but again I suspect it's reasonable to ask this question for *most* distributions. If that's not true then correct me.

**Edit** I only mean to refer to headers used by user space programs.

Comment: what do you mean by unix and linux headers

Comment: Well, I've found myself in situations where I had to include C++ headers first (like `<iostream>`), and then include platform specific headers (like `<inet/XXX.h>`). When the inclusions were revered, the compile would fail. (Or maybe the situation was vice-versa).

Comment: @redFIVE edited. Is that what you were looking for? I thought "unix headers" was a reasonable description so I might not understand something. Was it the "Unix and Linux" that was confusing?

Comment: Certainly if you're talking about things like `<unistd.h>` and the other usual suspects, if you couldn't use C++ to write UNIX programs it would never have become popular. Particularly if you're talking about Linux and g++/glibc, if there was ever an incompatibility that prevented C++ programs compiled with g++ from using the normal UNIX headers, it would be filed as a bug and fixed.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Those are exactly the suspects of interest. If you could find a link confirming that would be considered a bug in gcc I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: I don't have a link. The millions of people writing C++ programs on UNIX is reasonably strong evidence, though. gcc itself is in the process of being rewritten in C++, for instance. This kind of backwards compatibility is an explicit design goal of C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C standard headers like `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and so forth are specified in Appendix D of the C++ standard, which states:

> These are deprecated features, where *deprecated* is defined as:
>   Normative for the current edition of the Standard, but not guaranteed
>   to be part of the Standard in future revisions.

The non-deprecated C++ versions of the C standard headers have names like `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`, etc., and they technically put their definitions into the `std` (not global) namespace. So, to be 100% compliant with the non-deprecated part of the C++ spec, you need to write something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  std::printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

That said, to my knowledge, no existing implementation actually forces you to do this, and in my opinion it is unlikely any ever will. So in practice, you can safely use C standard headers in C++ without much concern.

Also, if you are on (e.g.) a POSIX system, you can generally use POSIX functionality from C++ equally safely. Certainly nobody is going to deliberately break any of this because users would revolt.

However, accidental breakage is conceivable when mixing paradigms. If both the platform and the language standard provide some feature, you should use one or the other but not both. In particular, I would not mix POSIX threading and synchronization mechanisms with standard C++11 threading and synchronization mechanisms, because it is easy to imagine an optimizer knowing too much about the latter and generating code incompatible with the former.

[Update, to elaborate somewhat]

`<unistd.h>` is an example of what I mean about platform-dependent functionality. It will generally work fine from C++, and neither the library nor the compiler developers will break it gratuitiously because that would be too annoying. So go ahead and call `getpid()` or `pipe()` or whatever.

But be aware that mixing paradigms raises all sorts of questions. To name just a few off the top of my head:

- Can you call `new` from a signal handler?
- Can you use `dup2` onto descriptor 0 to redirect `cin`?
- What POSIX functions can you call safely during static initialization (i.e. before `main` executes)?

These questions and others like them are not addressed by *any* spec. The answers depend on your specific implementation and could change between releases.

Having said all that... Just about every non-trivial C++ program relies on platform-specific functionality exposed by some C interface. So what you are describing will work fine in practice provided you (a) have some idea what is going on "under the hood"; (b) have reasonable expectations; and (c) do not attempt to mix standard and platform-specific paradigms.

Comment: The C standard library headers are indeed included in the headers Open Group requires of a Unix but the headers I had in mind are the ones not mentioned in the C++ standard, e.g. `unistd.h`.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: `unistd.h` is an example of what I meant in my last two paragraphs. See also the update I just added.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes: "standard headers" are *standard*.  You can safely use them regardless of platform.

2) Yes: you can mix C headers (e.g. `<stdio.h>`) with C++ headers (e.g. `<iostream>`) in the same C++ translation unit.

3) *NO*: you *should NOT* use *linux kernel* headers in a user mode program, nor vice versa.

Linux kernel headers are intended for kernel-mode drivers, *not* for "normal", user space applications.

Here is a bit more information:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27042/what-does-a-kernel-source-tree-contain-is-this-related-to-linux-kernel-headers
- http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders

Comment: Unix and Linux headers are not standard in the sense of C++ standard. `stdio.h` is covered by the C++ standard. Can you find a source on 1)? I think the phrase I should have used was "Linux API header". Does that make more sense?

Comment: Just don't conflate headers like "kernel/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64" with the headers in /usr/include (like "stdio.h").  The latter is for user-space programs; the former for kernel modules and the like.  That was my main point...